# Find parent table's first sibling - jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have 2 tables, where I have some rows with some image buttons. What I want to do is, when I click on the image button, is to SHOW the div that is placed right under the table which contains the clicked image button.

```
<table id="Table1">
  <tr>
     <td><input type="image" src="Images/info.jpg" class="infoButton" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div class="info">            
</div>

<table id="Table2">
  <tr>
     <td><input type="image" src="Images/info.jpg" class="infoButton" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div class="info">            
</div>
```

What I have done so far is this:

```
$('.infoButton').click(function () {                          
    $(this).closest('table').siblings().filter(":first").show();
});
```

This works when I click a button inside the 1st table. Then it shows the correct div (the one under table 1). When I click on a button inside table 2, then it again shows the same div. I want it to show the div under table 2.

Comment: It's really worth spending an hour just reading [the API documentation](http://api.jquery.com). It genuinely only takes that long, and it will dramatically improve how you use the library (and save you time asking questions like this).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.infoButton').click(function () {                          
    $(this).closest('table').next('div').show();
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4XhSA/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

Recommend using the jQuery `parents` function, it increases readability and built for the purpose.

`$('.infoButton').click(function () {

    $(this).parents('table').next('div').show();
});`